# Angularjs ng-click is not working after applying ng-pressstart and ng-pressend directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular application which was working ok on desktop browsers. But after I tried opening it on android chrome the `ng-click` was rarely working. After clicking 100 times it might work and trigger the click. After analyzing the code I got the reason, there is one js file which I created to create new angular directives:

```
var app;

var getOnTouchEndEventName = function () {
    var isTouchSupported = "ontouchend" in document;
    if (isTouchSupported) {
        return "touchend";
    } else {
        return "mouseup";
    }
};

var getOnTouchStartEventName = function () {
    var isTouchSupported = "ontouchend" in document;
    if (isTouchSupported) {
        return "touchstart";
    } else {
        return "mousedown";
    }
};

app.directive("ngPressstart", [function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind(getOnTouchStartEventName(), function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            scope.$apply(attrs["ngPressstart"]);
        });
    }
}]);

app.directive("ngPressend", [function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind(getOnTouchEndEventName(), function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            scope.$apply(attrs["ngPressend"]);
        });
    }
}]);
```

So there are two directives: `ng-pressstart` and `ng-pressend`, the purpose was to use one directive for mobile and desktop browsers. For example if its mobile then `getOnTouchEndEventName()` would return touchend. Otherwise its `mouseup`.

What is the way to fix this implementation?

The issue happens even if I'm not using those directives.

Comment: `var app;` at the beginning of this file seems quite out of place.... that's definitely not the right way to declare or retrieve an angular `app` module....

Comment: You can bind to multiple events by passing them as a space-delimited string to `bind`... e.g. `bind('mouseup touchstart', ...)`. That one or the other isn't available on the system doesn't matter (unless you explicitly don't want to support both on a touch-enabled laptop, for example).

Comment: @Claies I already have this in another file:  var app = angular.module('game1', []); where app is global parameter. So I decided not to create another global variable with the same name.

Comment: @sdgluck Interesting, dont know why I didn't do it that way. Anyway there are a lot of code using current approach. Any suggestions to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, the declaration at the beginning of this file is not the correct syntax for angular.  By declaring `var app;` in this file, you are unintentionally causing a name collision.

The proper way to add components to an angular module is to use the module getter syntax.

The *recommended* way to manage modules in angular is to not use a variable at all. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y021

For example, when declaring your angular app, instead of doing:

```
var app = angular.module('game1', []);
```

you can simply use:

```
angular.module('game1', []);
```

When declaring a component (controller, directive, filter, etc.), you can then use the chaining getter syntax.  https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y022

```
angular
  .module('game1')
  .directive("ngPressstart", [function () {
```

This ensures that you never have a naming collision, and makes your code more readable.